# AWS Glue Studio: - job runs but outputs empty files to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I'm using AWS Glue Studio to get data from an S3 Bucket in Parquet format, join the data and output it in JSON to another S3 bucket. The job runs successfully, but it creates dozens of empty (zero bytes) files in the destination S3. I have not changed the code manually, I've just used the UI.

The interesting bit is that the UI properly shows the result (in the Data preview tab), the issue seems to be the upload to S3.

Here is the Python code generated by Glue:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "X-parquet-s3", table_name = "entity1", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0"]
## @return: DataSource0
## @inputs: []
DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "X-parquet-s3", table_name = "entity1", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0")
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mappings = [("archive_reason_id", "string", "entity1_archive_reason_id", "string"), ("archived_by_user_id", "string", "entity1_archived_by_user_id", "string"), ("owner_user_id", "string", "entity1_owner_user_id", "string"), ("archived_at", "timestamp", "entity1_archived_at", "timestamp"), ("origin", "string", "entity1_origin", "string"), ("last_story_at", "timestamp", "entity1_last_story_at", "timestamp"), ("created_at", "timestamp", "entity1_created_at", "timestamp"), ("posting_id", "string", "entity1_posting_id", "string"), ("origin_id", "string", "entity1_origin_id", "string"), ("is_confidential", "boolean", "entity1_is_confidential", "boolean"), ("contact_id", "string", "entity1_contact_id", "string"), ("last_advanced_at", "timestamp", "entity1_last_advanced_at", "timestamp"), ("stage_entered_at", "timestamp", "entity1_stage_entered_at", "timestamp"), ("entity1_id", "string", "entity1_entity1_id", "string"), ("account_id", "string", "entity1_account_id", "string"), ("requisition_id", "string", "entity1_requisition_id", "string"), ("is_deleted", "boolean", "entity1_is_deleted", "boolean"), ("sourced_by_user_id", "string", "entity1_sourced_by_user_id", "string"), ("is_hired", "boolean", "entity1_is_hired", "boolean"), ("row_updated_at", "timestamp", "entity1_row_updated_at", "timestamp"), ("account_stage_id", "string", "entity1_account_stage_id", "string")], transformation_ctx = "Transform1"]
## @return: Transform1
## @inputs: [frame = DataSource0]
Transform1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = DataSource0, mappings = [("archive_reason_id", "string", "entity1_archive_reason_id", "string"), ("archived_by_user_id", "string", "entity1_archived_by_user_id", "string"), ("owner_user_id", "string", "entity1_owner_user_id", "string"), ("archived_at", "timestamp", "entity1_archived_at", "timestamp"), ("origin", "string", "entity1_origin", "string"), ("last_story_at", "timestamp", "entity1_last_story_at", "timestamp"), ("created_at", "timestamp", "entity1_created_at", "timestamp"), ("posting_id", "string", "entity1_posting_id", "string"), ("origin_id", "string", "entity1_origin_id", "string"), ("is_confidential", "boolean", "entity1_is_confidential", "boolean"), ("contact_id", "string", "entity1_contact_id", "string"), ("last_advanced_at", "timestamp", "entity1_last_advanced_at", "timestamp"), ("stage_entered_at", "timestamp", "entity1_stage_entered_at", "timestamp"), ("entity1_id", "string", "entity1_entity1_id", "string"), ("account_id", "string", "entity1_account_id", "string"), ("requisition_id", "string", "entity1_requisition_id", "string"), ("is_deleted", "boolean", "entity1_is_deleted", "boolean"), ("sourced_by_user_id", "string", "entity1_sourced_by_user_id", "string"), ("is_hired", "boolean", "entity1_is_hired", "boolean"), ("row_updated_at", "timestamp", "entity1_row_updated_at", "timestamp"), ("account_stage_id", "string", "entity1_account_stage_id", "string")], transformation_ctx = "Transform1")
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "X-parquet-s3", table_name = "contact_name", transformation_ctx = "DataSource1"]
## @return: DataSource1
## @inputs: []
DataSource1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "X-parquet-s3", table_name = "contact_name", transformation_ctx = "DataSource1")
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mappings = [("account_id", "string", "contact_name_account_id", "string"), ("row_updated_at", "timestamp", "contact_name_row_updated_at", "timestamp"), ("name", "string", "contact_name_name", "string"), ("contact_id", "string", "contact_name_contact_id", "string")], transformation_ctx = "Transform3"]
## @return: Transform3
## @inputs: [frame = DataSource1]
Transform3 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = DataSource1, mappings = [("account_id", "string", "contact_name_account_id", "string"), ("row_updated_at", "timestamp", "contact_name_row_updated_at", "timestamp"), ("name", "string", "contact_name_name", "string"), ("contact_id", "string", "contact_name_contact_id", "string")], transformation_ctx = "Transform3")
## @type: Join
## @args: [keys2 = ["entity1_contact_id"], keys1 = ["contact_name_contact_id"], transformation_ctx = "Transform2"]
## @return: Transform2
## @inputs: [frame1 = Transform3, frame2 = Transform1]
Transform2 = Join.apply(frame1 = Transform3, frame2 = Transform1, keys2 = ["entity1_contact_id"], keys1 = ["contact_name_contact_id"], transformation_ctx = "Transform2")
## @type: SelectFields
## @args: [paths = ["contact_name_name", "entity1_entity1_id", "contact_name_contact_id"], transformation_ctx = "Transform0"]
## @return: Transform0
## @inputs: [frame = Transform2]
Transform0 = SelectFields.apply(frame = Transform2, paths = ["contact_name_name", "entity1_entity1_id", "contact_name_contact_id"], transformation_ctx = "Transform0")
## @type: DataSink
## @args: [connection_type = "s3", format = "json", connection_options = {"path": "s3://X-sync-json/", "partitionKeys": []}, transformation_ctx = "DataSink0"]
## @return: DataSink0
## @inputs: [frame = Transform0]
DataSink0 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = Transform0, connection_type = "s3", format = "json", connection_options = {"path": "s3://X-sync-json/", "partitionKeys": []}, transformation_ctx = "DataSink0")
job.commit()
```

How can I debug this output? The only error that I can see on the error output (between dozens of logs) is this one, and it doesn't tell me much:

```
2021-07-29 19:28:23,213 ERROR [Thread-7] util.UserData (UserData.java:getUserData(70)): Error encountered while try to get user data java.lang.NullPointerException at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:871) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2726) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.UserData.getUserData(UserData.java:66) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.UserData.<init>(UserData.java:39) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.UserData.ofDefaultResourceLocations(UserData.java:52) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.buildSTSClient(AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.java:52) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.<clinit>(AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.java:17) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.rolemapping.DefaultS3CredentialsResolver.resolve(DefaultS3CredentialsResolver.java:22) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.CredentialsProviderOverrider.override(CredentialsProviderOverrider.java:25) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.executeOverriders(GlobalS3Executor.java:171) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:103) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:189) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:184) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:96) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AbstractAmazonS3Lite.getObjectMetadata(AbstractAmazonS3Lite.java:43) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:220) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:860) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1440) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.exists(EmrFileSystem.java:352) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSystemFolder.listFiles(FileLister.scala:227) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.DefaultPartitionFilesLister$$anonfun$_partitions$1.apply(FileSystemBookmark.scala:83) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.DefaultPartitionFilesLister$$anonfun$_partitions$1.apply(FileSystemBookmark.scala:81) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241) at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241) at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.DefaultPartitionFilesLister._partitions(FileSystemBookmark.scala:81) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.PartitionFilesListerUsingBookmark.initialFiltering$1(FileSystemBookmark.scala:337) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.PartitionFilesListerUsingBookmark.getNextBookmark$1(FileSystemBookmark.scala:469) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.PartitionFilesListerUsingBookmark.partitions(FileSystemBookmark.scala:569) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource$$anonfun$getDynamicFrame$9.apply(DataSource.scala:699) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource$$anonfun$getDynamicFrame$9.apply(DataSource.scala:677) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper$$anonfun$executeWithQualifiedScheme$1.apply(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:89) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper$$anonfun$executeWithQualifiedScheme$1.apply(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:89) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper.executeWith(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:82) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper.executeWithQualifiedScheme(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:89) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:676) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSource$class.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:94) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:658) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this:

```
2021-07-29 19:28:23,213 ERROR [Thread-7] util.UserData (UserData.java:getUserData(70)): Error encountered while try to get user data java.lang.NullPointerException at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:871) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2726) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.UserData.getUserData(UserData.java:66) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.UserData.<init>(UserData.java:39) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.UserData.ofDefaultResourceLocations(UserData.java:52) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.buildSTSClient(AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.java:52) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.<clinit>(AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.java:17) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.rolemapping.DefaultS3CredentialsResolver.resolve(DefaultS3CredentialsResolver.java:22) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.CredentialsProviderOverrider.override(CredentialsProviderOverrider.java:25) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.executeOverriders(GlobalS3Executor.java:171) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:103) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:189) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:184) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:96) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AbstractAmazonS3Lite.getObjectMetadata(AbstractAmazonS3Lite.java:43) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:220) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:860) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1440) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.exists(EmrFileSystem.java:352) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSystemFolder.listFiles(FileLister.scala:227) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.DefaultPartitionFilesLister$$anonfun$_partitions$1.apply(FileSystemBookmark.scala:83) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.DefaultPartitionFilesLister$$anonfun$_partitions$1.apply(FileSystemBookmark.scala:81) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241) at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241) at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.DefaultPartitionFilesLister._partitions(FileSystemBookmark.scala:81) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.PartitionFilesListerUsingBookmark.initialFiltering$1(FileSystemBookmark.scala:337) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.PartitionFilesListerUsingBookmark.getNextBookmark$1(FileSystemBookmark.scala:469) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.PartitionFilesListerUsingBookmark.partitions(FileSystemBookmark.scala:569) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource$$anonfun$getDynamicFrame$9.apply(DataSource.scala:699) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource$$anonfun$getDynamicFrame$9.apply(DataSource.scala:677) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper$$anonfun$executeWithQualifiedScheme$1.apply(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:89) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper$$anonfun$executeWithQualifiedScheme$1.apply(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:89) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper.executeWith(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:82) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FileSchemeWrapper.executeWithQualifiedScheme(FileSchemeWrapper.scala:89) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:676) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSource$class.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:94) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:658) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

is not an Error actually, this is happening on every Glue Job...
The Glue team assured me that you should not worry about it.

Can you try to repartition the DynamicFrame before writing by calling

```
repartitioned = Transform0.repartition(1)
```

You can change the 1 to the number of files you want in the end.
This may fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and explanation. Adding this did solve the problem. It generated a single file of 1.8MB. 

Can you help me understand why does this happens? Does it try to break it down so much to the point where it empties the files? Just to be clear, every single file that was generated before was empty, this 1.8MB was somehow discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Please check connection details in AWS Glue Catalog. I faced similar issue and error logs showed database connection issue. I corrected database connection details in Glue Catalog. I made no changes in script.